# Memory allocation order in c++

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I've written the following code trying to solve a challenge which requests an array-like structure without using them:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 132,y = 33,z = 87;

    int *i = &x;

    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
    std::cout << &x << " " << &y << " " << &z << "\n";
    std::cout << i << " " << i-1 << " " << i-2 << "\n";
    std::cout << *i << " " << *(i-1) << " " << *(i-2) << "\n";   
}
```

I found that the difference between 2 variables' addresses (&y-&x) to be -1 and I've adapted the code subsequently
I don't understand why the last defined variable is allocated "before" (meaning, a previous address).

I would have think &y-&x = 1, honestly.

Can you give me a few pointers? (no pun intended :P)
Oh, I know that code is bad practice - but does it have drawbacks or exceptions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't make any valid assumptions about how, where or in what order these local variables will be allocated.

Comment: I could not assume even that &y-&x is equal to &z-&y?

Comment: as I said above, you can't make *any valid assumptions* about this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This practice is as bad as it can get.

The stack layout is not specified; even if the variable actually has a on-stack representation (which it may not have, if you don't take the variable address and the optimizer moves it to registers), the order between variables and the padding (i.e. the difference between pointers) is not specified.

You can get a pointer to the local variable, but you can't do pointer arithmetics on it - you get undefined behavior (unless, of course, we're talking about local array variable).

Finally, there is at least one platform where abs(&y - &x) is never 1 (because stack vars are 16b-aligned).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said I couldn't use arrays. I assume there is not a safe way to do that, isn't? Oh maybe a better way could be i+(&y-&x) and i+2*(&y-&x). In this way the code will not be dependent on my platform

Comment: i + (&y - &x) will likely work on all practical compilers, but is still technically undefined. i + 2 * (&y - &x) will fail on different compilers, depending on optimization options and other factors.

Answer (score 3):

Because the stack grows downwards on your machine. There are some helpful diagrams for the Intel x86 about half-way down [this page](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html).

Comment: Thanks for the diagrams, they are perfect for intel cpus

Comment: @framp: @TonyK. That is a simplistic representation of how it works conceptually only. The compiler makes no such grantees and I suspect there are systems that do not do this for security reasons. There is actually no reason why stack frames may not be dynamically allocated within the heap like any other dynamic memory.

Comment: @Martin York: I pitched my answer at the OP's perceived level of experience, but I don't think I was being simplistic. Simplified, perhaps. But what are these 'security reasons'? I am dubious.

Comment: @TonyK: Its part of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_and_safety_features_new_to_Windows_Vista). Its not a security panacea. But it makes things harder for attackers.

Comment: @Martin York: That link is certainly interesting! But I didn't see anything about allocating stack frames from the heap. I'm still dubious.

Comment: @TonyK: From ASDL page. <quote>the stack and heap allocated is randomly decided<quote>

Comment: @Martin York: I take that to mean that the address of the stack is random. Not that stack frames are allocated from the heap.

Comment: @TonyK: You may be correct there. But I assure you if he read all the supplied links you will find it. Alternatively you could ask the question on SO.

Comment: @Martin York: What will I (he) find? (You used some tricky pronouns there.) And why would I want to ask a question on SO?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can place variables wherever it likes. On many current operating systems, the stack grows downwards, so if the compiler naively allocates variables in stack order, a variable that is declared later in located at a lower memory position. But again, it is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Not only that, the compiler might not even allocate a variable at all if it can optimize it away.